# Access Runtime Installation Failure

Tags: ms-access, installation, ms-office

We are getting the following error on a user's computer:

> 1: 1935
>   2: {3194323D-C74C-40E0-A864-B677608E5D6E}
>   3: 0x80131049
>   4: IAssemblyCacheItem
>   5: Commit
>   6: Policy.14.0.Microsoft.Vbe.Interop,
>   fileversion="15.0.4420.1017",version="15.0.0.00000000",culture="neutral",
>   publicKeyToken="71E9BCE111E9429C",processorArchitecture="MSIL"*

I'm not sure whether it's related but there is a copy of `MSACCESS.exe` already on the machine in

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Office.Desktop.Access_16040.10325.20082.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Office16
```

which I believe to be the location where apps purchased from the Microsoft Store are located.  The user assures me that she hasn't shelled out and bought Access and in any case, clicking on an Access file doesn't open the file and there is no trace of the installation icon apart from this folder.

My questions are:

1. Does anyone know what the above error means?
2. Does anyone know how to remove this apparent partial installation of Access?

Comment: Did you fix this problem somehow?

Answer (score 1):

@Paul - we eventually fixed this by getting more serious with the uninstall:

Type the following commands from a PowerShell command prompt:

"(Get-AppxPackage -Name Microsoft.Office.Desktop).Dependencies | Remove-AppxPackage"

then

"Get-AppxPackage -Name Microsoft.Office.Desktop | Remove-AppxPackage"

That will typically throw an error if everything is already removed.

Then to verify that it is indeed removed, this command should return nothing.

"(Get-AppxPackage -Name Microsoft.Office.Desktop).Dependencies"

Thanks for your response as it offers an alternative if the above doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

So I don't know a lot on this error but i had the same problem then after cleaning the registry with CCleaner and then retrying to install office it was fixed. Let me know if it work